# How do we disable specific warnings from C preprocessing

Tags: c, makefile

I have enabled `-Werror` for C pre processing command to treat warnings as errors.
Basically i wanted to `only` treat `redefined` warnings as errors. And all other warnings should **not be** treated as errors.

```
  In file included from /home/test/version24/test.spec:35:0,
                 /test/release/base_version.spec:93:0: warning: "CD_MK_FILE" redefined
 #define CD_MK_FILE                4

In file included from /home/test/version23/mss_litter.spec:19:0,
                 from 
/test/release/base_version23.spec:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CD_MK_FILE                3
```

Is there any flag in to treat only redefined warnings as errors.
Thank you!

Comment: I believe its `-Werror=...`, where `...` is the name of the flag that enables the warning, which should be included in the warning message.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1047003/12257925) might help you

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: If this was the gcc or clang compiler, I believe it would tell you which flag was the flag in question, at the end of the warning, and in square brackets. Ex: `warning: blah blah [-Wblah-blah]`, so that you could know to disable `blah-blah` if you want. I don't see that here. I don't know what your compiler is.

Comment: Do you really mean specifically for the pre-processor only (i.e. running `cpp` stand-alone rather than the compiler driver?  That would be unusual.  Your fragment/example is unhelpful, showing an example warning that does not appear to relate to the code.  Provide a real warning and real and complete code that will generate it so we can be sure we know what you require.

Comment: @user3386109, your (now-deleted) comment was really helpful. Thanks! I referenced you in my answer.

Comment: I have not seen the comment... Could you please repost ?

Comment: @Johnney, it was just that in the clang compiler, the warning of interest is `-Wmacro-redefined`. I've updated my answer with that. But, most importantly, you still haven't answered which compiler you're using, nor if you are running the `cpp` C preprocessor utility directly instead of a compiler. Clifford has an excellent question.

Comment: you are right, I am running cpp preprocessor directly. So here should i try -Werror = -Wmacro-redefined ?

Comment: What does `cpp --version` tell you? Now we need to know which brand of `cpp` you're running. Also, I've never run `cpp` in my life. Normally, if you want to stop the compilation stage early, I just call `gcc` with some flags to indicate that. Ex: `man gcc` tells me to use `gcc -c` to stop before linking, so you just get .o object files. Or, if you want to see all preprocessed intermediate .i files, I run `gcc -save-temps=obj`, [as I explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56482777/4561887).

Comment: I am using cpp from gcc-6 version as follows :- /home/toolroot/CCACHE/ccache_3_7_6_nv/install_dir/GCC/gcc-6.4.0-2/bin/cpp

Answer (score 4):

### Answer to the specific question

How to only treat `macro-redefined` warnings as errors, and let all other warnings *not* be treated as errors:

1. In the gcc compiler: *you can't*.
2. In the LLVM clang compiler: use `-Werror=macro-redefined`.

### Generic answer to just the *title* of the question: how do we enable or disable specific compiler warnings or errors?

For `gcc`/`g++` and `clang` compilers, try:

```bash
# To disable -Werror just for warning -Wwhatever
-Wno-error=whatever

# To **enable** errors just for this one -Wwhatever warning
-Werror=whatever
```

For the clang compiler, you'd use `-Wno-error=macro-redefined`, to *disable* that error for the `-Wmacro-redefined` warning only, and you'd use `-Werror=macro-redefined` to *enable* an error *only* for that warning.

See here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wmacro-redefined. Thanks for the comment under the question, [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109)!

See the list of all possible warnings and errors here:

1. For the gcc compiler: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html
2. For the clang compiler (which is gcc-compatible, by design): https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

For example, from the gcc link above:

> ### `-Werror=`
>
> Make the specified warning into an error. The specifier for a warning is appended; for example `-Werror=switch` turns the warnings controlled by `-Wswitch` into errors. This switch takes a negative form, to be used to negate `-Werror` for specific warnings; for example `-Wno-error=switch` makes `-Wswitch` warnings not be errors, even when `-Werror` is in effect.
>
> The warning message for each controllable warning includes the option that controls the warning. That option can then be used with `-Werror=` and `-Wno-error=` as described above. (Printing of the option in the warning message can be disabled using the `-fno-diagnostics-show-option` flag.)
>
> Note that specifying `-Werror=foo` automatically implies `-Wfoo`. However, `-Wno-error=foo` does not imply anything.

### Other References:

1. The [comment by @HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72038919/how-do-we-disable-specific-warnings-from-c-preprocessing/72039051#comment127289842_72038919)
2. [my Q&A] [How can I disable a C/C++ `-Werror` build error in Bazel? (AKA: how to turn OFF specific warnings already turned on by `-Wall -Werror`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64111154/4561887)

### Related:

1. In case you ever need to control just a few lines of code, this is incredibly useful too: [How to disable GCC warnings for a few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47518775/4561887)

Comment: Okay...In my case what would be the -Werror=<????> , I could not find exact string to placed , Inroder to just enable referined warnings as errors.

Comment: @Johnney, I don't know what a "redefined" warning is. I don't recall that one. Can you copy and paste the *exact* warning or error you're seeing please, into your question?

Comment: If we have same macro/variable defined with different values at two different files, If we try to preprocess those files , CPP complains with warnings variable has been redefined. I am just using sample CPP (from gcc compiler) command to preprocessing the files.

Comment: @Johnney, thanks. What does "CPP" mean? To me, that means "C Plus Plus" (C++), but you have tagged this question C. Also, C++ never complains. It's a standard written in a huge huge huge document for sale. A compiler complains, however. So we need to know which compiler you have and have a minimal runnable example that we can test ourselves.

Comment: Sorry. CPP i mean c pre processer

Comment: This does not answer the question (the answer seems to be "It's not possible")

Comment: `-Werror=macro-redefined` is for clang only, which is not useful for `cpp` (being based on `gcc` which also does not have this option) as per the original question

Comment: @ljden, I see what you mean. You are correct. Answer updated. I meant it largely to be a generic answer tailored to the _title_ of the question moreso than to the specifics of the question.

Comment: appreciate it, and yes, the question title and body aren't quite in alignment. I've suggested an edit to the answer and I have flipped the downvote :)